# Two different Web8 CMS server pointing to same topology manager database

Tags: web8, topology-manager

I have set up SDL Web8 (CMS, CD) on two different machine in following way.

I have Server0[for databases], Server1[Setup 1#] and Server2[Setup 2#].

[Setup 1#]

- Created databases for “cm”, “topology”, “broker”, and “experience” in
  Server0 for both Server1 and Server2.
- Installed SDL Web8 CMS, Content Delivery on Server1 using databases
  created in Server0.
- Publishing is working fine to broker1, webapplication1 is running
  fine in Server1.
- Everything is working amazing.

[Setup 2#]

- Then created Server2 by cloning Server1 machine.
- Created separate set of databases again for “cm”, “topology”,
  “broker”, and “experience” in Server0.
- CMS and Content Delivery in cloned in Server2, are customized to use
  these newly created set of databases in Server0.
- Publishing is working fine to broker2, Webapplication2 is running in
  Server2.

I realized both Server1 and Server2 are using same topology Manager Database but working fine. But in future PowerShell command for 1 may impact other as well.

I am not able to figure out a way to change the topology database. Please suggest a way to change the Database for one of these?
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please re-point the topology manager database to another database [Setup#2].

1. Navigate to server 2 %Tridion_Home%\TopologyManager\web
2. Decrypt server 2 database section in web.config
3. Change database settings in node in web.config
4. Encrypt the config file
5. Restart IIS [Server #2]

For more information click here and see below - [How to Decrypt a web.config File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/bb986792.aspx)

Copy the config file in temporary directory.

To decrypt the configuration file, start with making a temporary directory somewhere to put the Tridion.ContentManager.config file. For this example we'll use c:\temporary .

For decrypt the webconfig parts :

```
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -pdf "database" c:\temporary
```

After entering this command, the database section in the config is decrypted and unprotected. So you need to encrypt again by running below command:

```
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -pef "database" c:\temporary -prov "TridionRsaProtectedConfigurationProvider"
```

Once done all place the file in below location:

```
%Tridion_Home%\TopologyManager\web
```

Comment: Yeah this worked on my local test environment. Hopefully it would work on  "Server2".. Thanks a lot.